# Ways for custom logging in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am in progress of refactoring a C++ application of mine. Before I used a macro like

```
LOG("something interesting") // 1
LOG("something ended")       // 2
LOG("foo: " << bar)          // 3
```

My idea now was to write a `Log` class like so:

```
Log(std::string _init_message):
    init_message(_init_message)
{   PrintLogLine(init_message + "   ...");}
~Log() 
{   PrintLogLine(init_message + " done.");}
```

to get "automatic" logging of specific actions (i.e. when they start, stop + additionally timings etc.) when I use it like

```
void ActionXYZ() {
   Log log("xyz");
   // do stuff
}
```

Where I am struggling is in defining a way to make it work for case 3). In Java I could use a method which takes one `String` argument since the compiler takes care of automatically string building. What possibilities do I have in C++?

Can I make it work so that I can use it like either one option?

```
 // in "do stuff"
 log("foo:" + bar); // OR
 log << "foo:" << bar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, you could use Boost.Format. It also helps with the problem of int-to-string conversions, etc. It might get a bit verbose, though — to avoid calling `.str()` to call `std::string` constructor, you could make one that accepts `boost::format` directly.

```
Log log(boost::format("foo %1% bar") % 42); // with Log(boost::format)
Log log((boost::format("foo %1% bar") % 42).str()); // with only Log(std::string)
```

Refer to [Boost.Format documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/doc/format.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Two immediate possibilities come to mind. The first is to take advantage of std::string appending:

```
Log log(std::string("foo:") + bar);
```

The second is to make more `log` constructors that take additional parameters:

```
Log log("foo:", bar);
```

Comment: I already tried the first option, but its applicability seems limited. This `log(std::string("foo: ") + 2 + " units");` does not compile...

Comment: @dcn, you should have mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: sorry, I thought I indicated that with my comment about Java string building.

Comment: @dcn that tidbit gets lost on us who aren't familiar with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider using [Boost.Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) for your logging.  Logging can be a complex thing; it's useful to get a fully formed implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a logging class that inherits from std::strstream.

```
class Mstream : public std::strstream
{
  public:
  Mstream() : std::strstream(Buffer = new char[BUFLEN], BUFLEN, ios::out);
  ostream& endf(ostream& s);
  void Write();

  private:
  char* Buffer;
};
```

Now you can log output as,

```
Mstream m; 
m <<"Foo"<<s<<endf;
```

In endf(ostream& s) you can cast ostream to Mstream and call the Write(). In Write(), you format the output and print it to console or to a file.